# How to call application menu programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have non-rectangular transparent window with custom style.

```
<Window
    x:Class="TestWindow" x:Name="Window"
    Width="350" Height="450"  AllowsTransparency="True"  WindowStyle="None"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" FontSize="14 px" FontFamily="Fonts/#Tahoma" 
Background="Transparent">
```

I have a grid for title and system buttons  and want to show application menu by right click on it. Currently app menu showing only by pressing ALT+Spacebar. 
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after a two hours spent in Google I finally found a solution.

Step1: define RECT structure like this:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 public struct RECT
     {
          public int Left;
          public int Top;
          public int Right;
          public int Bottom;
     }
```

Step2: import two user32.dll functions:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int TrackPopupMenu(int hMenu, int wFlags, int x, int y, int nReserved, int hwnd, ref RECT lprc);
```

Step3: add 'right mouse button click on header' event handler:

```
private void headerArea_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       {               
          switch (e.ChangedButton)
            {
              case MouseButton.Right:
                   {
                      // need to get handle of window
                      WindowInteropHelper _helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);

                      //translate mouse cursor porition to screen coordinates
                      Point p = PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(this));

                      //get handler of system menu
                      IntPtr systemMenuHandle = GetSystemMenu(_helper.Handle, false);

                      RECT rect = new RECT();
                      // and calling application menu at mouse position.
                      int menuItem = TrackPopupMenu(systemMenuHandle.ToInt32(), 1,(int)p.X, (int) p.Y, 0, _helper.Handle.ToInt32(), ref rect);
                      break;
                   }                   
             }   
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change Raeno's code as follows to get the menu items to work...

```
//Get the hWnd, because I need to re-use it...
int hWnd = helper.Handle.ToInt32();
//Change the wFlags from 1 to TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD...
int menuItem = TrackPopupMenu(systemMenuHandle.ToInt32(), TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD, (int)point.X, (int)point.Y, 0, hWnd, ref rect);

// The return value from TrackPopupMenu now need posting...
if (menuItem != 0)
{
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, menuItem, 0);
}
```

This required the following declarations...

```
private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
private const int TPM_RIGHTBUTTON = 0x0002;
private const int TPM_RETURNCMD = 0x0100;

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int PostMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```