# How to show the Window's System Menu Programmatically When FormBorderStyle Is None?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have a Form with the FormBorderStyle set to None, and I have also made my own little GUI replacing the Title Bar, I'm trying to find a way to show the Menu that shows up whenever you right click the title bar or click the icon on the title bar

[image: System Menu shown on Notepad]

I have tried using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279525/how-to-call-application-menu-programmatically) but after calling the function nothing happened, I'm at a loss now and I cannot find more resources about this.

Comment: Did you see/try the other answer posted there?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I get `The type 'WindowsApplication1.Form1' already contains a definition for 'WM_SYSCOMMAND'` and if I just use the form's variable it just complains about not being able to convert to int, if I cast it it builds but doesn't do anything else

Comment: @xproot Are you sure that you are at a loss? It is just a redefinition of a variable. Delete other one.

Comment: @jtxkopt edited, I had deleted the rest of the comment without noticing

Comment: @xproot The link you provided has already an answer to solve your problem. You should show how different your problem are from other question.

Comment: With more tinkering, I found out if I set the Form back to Sizable the code works...? My objective is to have it working without a form border so...

Comment: `IntPtr hwnd = User32.GetSystemMenu(form.Handle, true or false);` always returns 0 with `FormBorderStyle.None` so it's not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch window's System Menu on custom window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410121/launch-windows-system-menu-on-custom-window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the border style of `Form` is set to `FormBorderStyle.None`, `GetSystemMenu()` always returns a `NULL` handle.

Because you remove some important Window Styles from `HWND` when you set the border style to `None`, this function doesn't return a `HMENU`.
Probably, it does some checks if the window has a title bar or not. This is why it returns `NULL`.

The workaround for the issue is to get the menu handle before setting the `FoormBorderStyle` to `None`.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int TrackPopupMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uFlags, int x, int y,
       int nReserved, IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr prcRect);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
    private IntPtr hMenu;
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the system menu and set the border style after that.
        hMenu = GetSystemMenu(Handle, false);
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int menuIdentifier = TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, 0x102, Control.MousePosition.X, Control.MousePosition.Y, 0, Handle, IntPtr.Zero);
        if(menuIdentifier != 0)
        {
            PostMessage(Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)menuIdentifier, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful with `SendMessage()` here. You may want to use `PostMessage()` instead

Comment: Great solution, works like a charm! Is it possible to activate the "Size" entry if the form's WindowState is FormWindowState.Normal? My borderless form then has imaginary borders to resize it. I'm building an exact copy (colors and behavior) of the Visual Studio 2022 window (which has the "Size" entry enabled in FormWindowState.Normal).

Comment: Never mind, I found it myself. Use GetMenuItemID(hMenu, nPos) to get the ID of the entry in its position and then use EnableMenuItem(hMenu, wIDEnableItem, wEnable) to enable it. `[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "GetMenuItemID")]
private static extern IntPtr GetMenuItemID(IntPtr hMenu, int nPos);
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EnableMenuItem")]
private static extern IntPtr EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, IntPtr wIDEnableItem, IntPtr wEnable);` CAUTION: wEnable must be 0 (zero) for enabled and 1 for disabled.

Comment: I already don't mind :) OP was interested in showing the entire system menu, not a specific menu item. But the trick stays the same as you understood it: get the handle beforeward, cache it and show it when you need. Glad that you solved your problem :)